# Did other countries stop recognizing Austria, after the German annexation?

Tags: world-war-two, nazi-germany

In World War II, Germany annexed Austria, thereby jeopardizing the lives of many Jews, including Lisa Meitner. According to *The Nuclear Express* by Thomas C. Reed and Danny B. Stillman, Lisa Meitner found it hard to emigrate outside of Austria because her Austrian passport was no longer valid, because Austria wasn't a country. Did the allied powers stop recognizing Austria as a country?

Comment: Don't have time to look at it, but I know it was quite a while before England switched their recognition from Czechoslovakia's puppet government to its Government-in-exile, because I'm reading about that right now. So I'm pretty sure when I *do* look it up, the answer will be yes.

Comment: @T.E.D. Where are you reading about that?

Comment: Madeleine Albright's [Prague Winter](https://www.amazon.com/Prague-Winter-Personal-Remembrance-1937-1948/dp/0062030345). Her ghost writer (I looked him up once but I forget his name atm) is really good. Its a depressing subject though, which always slows down my reading drastically.

Comment: I don't think Lisa Meitner is a good example, as she only tried to move to (at first) Denmark, then Holland (and then to Sweden).  Denmark refused to accept the Austrian passport, but apparently Holland didn't care (in the description from the book "Before the Fallout", the main danger in going to Holland was from the German side... the SS frequently searched trains and kept people without proper paperwork from leaving).  I think she only had an Austrian passport when going from Holland to Sweden, in Aug. 1938.

Comment: ... more to the point, in July 1938 the German government stopped allowing Jewish scientists to leave the country.

Comment: Germany annexed Austria **before** WWII.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~rwest/link-suggestion/wpcd_2008-09_augmented/wp/a/Anschluss.htm

> Austria ceased to exist as a fully independent nation until late 1945. A Provisional Austrian Government was set up on April 27, 1945 and was legally recognized by the Allies in the following months, but it was not until 1955 that Austria regained full sovereignty.